# Exploit by overwriting relative address?

Tags: exploit

I see a lot of exploits overwrite an absolute address to gain code execution. I wonder if there are vulnerabilities which offer the possibility to overwrite relative addresses.

Can you imagine a situation where is would be possible to overwrite a relative address?

Do you know any real world vulnerability where you can overwrite a relative address?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean using the address of a jmp esp-20 instead of a jmp esp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be much more difficult because you would need to use an offset each time. Various solutions exist, depending on which technique is used:

If **ASLR** is used, you don't know for sure where your shellcode is located, but you can still bypass this by spraying. Also only the base address is randomized, not the function offset, and you can [return to plt](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/bypassing-aslr-part-i/).

**nX/DEP** also has it's flaws, for example Java requests memory by PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE and thus makes it executable.

But generally, for most known exploits to work, the address must be absolute. In a traditional buffer overflow on the stack, the shell code is part of the data which triggers the overflow, so it is in the buffer. The return address is absolute so it is not sufficient for the attacker to know the code of the attacked function; the attacker must also know what is the stack depth at that moment, and this depends on previous application behavior. Without the stack depth, you would have no clue how big the offset is.

Comment: I don't think that this is correct when ASLR is in use.

Comment: You are right, I corrected my post. ASLR makes it harder, but there are ways around it.